# WPF datagrid binded with list not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid binded to a list through

```
public List<IHWModbusTcpTableItem> HoldingRegisters { get; set; }
```

and then

```
m_dtgHoldRegs.ItemsSource = m_Table.HoldingRegisters;
```

to update the datagrid I redo the line above. But after a long time this engenders memory leak and other problems.

Therefore I think that it would be better to set the source only once and then update.

So the first thing I did is changing the list to an observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<IHWModbusTcpTableItem> HoldingRegisters { get; set; }
```

and then only once set the items source. All the other times only update:

```
m_dtgHoldRegs.UpdateLayout();
m_dtgHoldRegs.Items.Refresh();
```

unfortunately that didn't work.

---

OK according to what I have been suggested I have added this:

```
public class CTableModbusItem : IHWModbusTcpTableItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CTableModbusItem(string label, ushort addr, short regValue)
    {
        Label = label;
        Address = addr;
        RegValue_Decimal = regValue;
    }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public ushort Address { get; set; }

    public void UpdateTable()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("RegValue_Decimal");
    }

    private int _regValue_Decimal;
    public int RegValue_Decimal
    {
        get { return _regValue_Decimal; }
        set
        {
            _regValue_Decimal = value;
            RegValue_Binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');//8bit
            RegValue_Hex = Convert.ToString(value, 8);
            if (value > 32)
                RegValue_Ascii = Convert.ToChar(value);
        }
    }

    public string RegValue_Binary { get; set; }
    public string RegValue_Hex { get; set; }
    public char RegValue_Ascii { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

and when I want to update I do that on a timer:

```
    for (int iii = 0; iii < m_Table.HoldingRegisters.Count(); iii++)
        m_Table.HoldingRegisters[iii].UpdateTable();
```

so now I see that the this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); is hit and it's not null but nothing happens the same

Comment: normally ObservableCollection alone will suffice, without UpdateLayout and Items.Refresh

Comment: ObservableCollections - "Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed." which means if you're changing the content of the collection it's not raising the event that the collection has updated.

Comment: Have you tryed implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and changed your `HoldingRegisters`property to one with a backing field and rising `PropertyChanged`?

You don't have to set your `ItemsSource` when you update your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for it was not working: I was recreating all the times the observable collection and that was ruining the binding. Thanks for helping